# Can we have square bracket snippets for posts?

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

We've all (well, most of us) used the square bracket snippets in comments and chat. Things like `[main] [meta] [faq] [about] [so] [mso]`.

Can we please get them for the main posts as well? Especially useful in Meta sites (where you refer to the [faq], [chat] or [about] pages).

Comment: When would you ever use that outside of comments on main sites?

Comment: It would be used on meta sites, I'm sure .. but not quite sure about the main sites.

Comment: @Mat: That's why I said "especially useful in meta sites". However, since the editor is the same, I don't think it's such a big deal to enable it on main sites as well, for whatever reason you may need it. (I've seen a similar answer on [site.se], it reads...)

Comment: As an aside, though I guess it is not a problem: comments are converted into HTML when the page is rendered. However, the HTML of the main posts is cooked/cached when saved. Hence, `[faq]` would be changed into `http://stackoverflow.com/faq` upon saving, and later changes of the target URL would not affect old posts until they are edited.

Comment: @Arjan: I don't follow?

Comment: How is *"I've seen a similar answer on [site.se], it reads..."* ever useful? Shouldn't you link to a specific post instead?

Comment: As for the caching: handling of posts is different from handling of comments. If this would be implemented, then existing posts wouldn't suddenly show anything special for `[faq]`, if the old post would hold that text. But I guess it's all theoretical; to me, this would be too much of a deviation from Markdown, with little benefit.

Comment: The only place I can see this being useful is in comments. Actual questions/answers on main usually won't have to refer to things like \[faq\], \[chat\] or \[meta\].

Comment: Yes please! I've wanted to use this countless times on meta.

Comment: @Arjan I would add [meta.tex/228](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) type of links, too.

Answer (score -1):

I agree. Sometimes in an answer I've been tempted to direct the gentle asker to Just Read The Fine FAQ or some such. If it isn't very useful, well, it won't be used much. Or do the Powers That Be On SE (hallowed be Their Reputations!) foresee misuse?

Comment: Shouldn't that answer be a comment then? :)

Comment: Perhaps, but sometimes to get a point across you need to write a program snippet (doesn't fit into a comment), or the (gentle) nudge to _also_ check the FAQ is not all of the answer.

Comment: I would probably disconnect the two. One comment and then purely an answer.